# QList Inheritance leads to class not recognized as a type by foreach

Tags: qt, class, types

With the following code

```
class Section : public QList<Property>
{
public:
    explicit Section();
    explicit Section(QString name);
    Property getPropertyNamed(QString name);
    QString getName();
private:
    QString *m_name;
};


Property Section::getPropertyNamed(QString name)
{
    Property toReturn;

    foreach (Property loopOn, this)
    {
        if(loopOn.getName() == name)
            toReturn = loopOn;
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

The compiler throws the following error. I did dig in the source generating the error, but it's frankly way above my level of understanding but it DID seem to be a template of the foreach instruction.

```
error: 'Section* const' is not a class, struct, or union type
     typename T::const_iterator i, e;
```

So basically,
   - What is wrong exactly in there?
   - How can I fix it?!

[Title is only a wild guess of what is actually happening here, will edit if necessary]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `this` is a pointer to `QList<Property>`, but you have to use the class instance itself, i.e write:

```
foreach (Property loopOn, *this) {
    [..]
}
```